# Programmatically dispatching key characters to input/contenteditable

Tags: javascript, dom

I can set the value of an input-style DOM elements (`input`/`div contenteditable=true`) quite easily, by either setting their `.value` or `innerText` properties via JS.

But is it possible to dispatch keyboard events to them, loaded with a character, so that it inserts the dispatched character to the current cursor position?

Here's an example that doesn't work.

```js
'use strict'

const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const editable = document.querySelector('#editable')

btn.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  // prevent unfocus when clicking button
  e.preventDefault()
  
  const customEvt = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
    bubbles: true, 
    cancelable: true, 
    key: 'X', 
    char: 'X'
  })

  editable.dispatchEvent(customEvt)
})
```

```css
#editable {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<p> Make sure the editable is focused before pressing button</p>
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<button id="btn"> Add 'X' character at cursor position</button>
```

### Why I need this:

We are building a symbols keyboard for an app, that will allow users to add symbols to the current cursor position.

Tracking the current cursor position in a `contenteditable`, so we can insert the clicked symbol, is error-prone and requires extra (and often ugly) code. I'd like to avoid it.

I'm guessing this can't be done, as it could be a security risk but It never hurts to ask.

Comment: i googled "simulate enter key js" and found something last week that worked, it was a SO link

Comment: @dandavis Are you sure it was not a Selenium thing?

Comment: yes. i found a lot of link that didn't work, but was able to modify the enter key one to use any key; i don't recall what made it different, only that it worked when other's didn't.

Comment: Guess that's encouraging.

Comment: I don't think you can manually fire keyboard events for security reasons. But I could be wrong

Comment: I'm guessing the same, but as I state in the question, it never hurts to ask.

Comment: Right, well if you decide to go the `value` route, there is a `selectionStart` field that gives you the current cursor position.

Comment: @infamoustrey For multiline text it becomes terribly ugly and unreliable.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides how so?

Comment: Can't iterate why in a comment, but I've carefully tried it and it was unreliable as hell. If you have a working snippet (and doing what I described in the OP is not possible), I'd gladly accept an answer from you. Kind of help-vampiring here, but you unwittingly invited it.

Comment: This will prevent you unless you are not in a browser : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't fake a keypress, but you can use document.execCommand.insertText, which should give more or less the same result. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand

```js
'use strict'

const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const editable = document.querySelector('#editable')

btn.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  // prevent unfocus when clicking button
  e.preventDefault() 
  console.log(document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'X'));
  

  
})
```

```css
#editable {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<p> Make sure the editable is focused before pressing button</p>
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<button id="btn"> Add 'X' character at cursor position</button>
```